# Avoid divide by zero error in Spotfire with SQL data

Tags: sql, spotfire, divide-by-zero

I'm currently attempting to replicate a report that stored data in-memory, with the new report connected with SQL and data entirely external. In the old report, we had some visualizations with sum([column1]) / sum([column2]) in lots of different cross tables etc. Sometimes a value would be 0, but the old report seems to automatically replace all divide by zero errors with just 0. However the new report keeps giving "An error occurred when executing a query in the external data source" - dividing by 0. Is there any equivalent to Excel's IFERROR function? Or try / except in Python? SN function did not work, I guess as the values are not null, they are errors. It would be much simpler to just change the custom expressions in visualizations than to have to make a new calculated column corresponding to every existing column changing all 0 to NULL etc. I cannot just replace values in the "data in analysis" tab as it is external data that I do not have access to alter. Would an IronPython script work? There are 50+ visualizations in this report so I would rather not write 50+ scripts but if I have to I will.

Comment: try `case when column2 = 0 then 0 else column1/column2 end`

Comment: I tried that. This is what I typed: `case  
when [three_year_expected]=0 then 0
else Sum(three_year_actual) / Sum([three_year_expected])
end`. It gives a new error: Specify an aggregation method.

Comment: Omg, can't believe I didn't catch that I needed to sum the when clause as well. Been a long day. After fixing that it works, thanks! Now just have to figure out why it's giving output in some and 0 in others despite copy-pasting but that's a different problem.